# not able to boot any OS windows 7 or Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, live-cd

My problem is that i can't boot to Ubuntu but i have Ubuntu installed. The problem is that by default is booting for Windows7 that is not working. And so i can't run any OS. My question is using liveCD of Ubuntu, how can I change my boot default, so i can run Ubuntu? Before i restart have a look at [boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10615465/).

I tried [How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)  and I tried this `grub-install /dev/sda` it occurs:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this LDM has no Embedding Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..sudo fdisk -l
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

How can I dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows?

Comment: It looks like you are using Dynamic rather than Basic volumes under Windows. There's a good writeup on this by OldFred. Post #2 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102917

Comment: To change the default Grub menu entry, mount the partition with your Ubuntu installation and run `grub-set-default --boot-directory=/path/to/ubuntu/root/boot <MENU_ENTRY>`. Look at the [manual pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/grub-set-default.8.html) (`man grub-set-default`) for details.